# zip file download not working in IE6

Tags: javascript, zip

I have given the javascript code like this

```
self.location = OmanPath() 
              + "Customer/Registration/UploadedPhoto/SampleImages.zip";
```

But this is not working in IE6. What may be the reason

This code not working for zip file download. It is working in IE7 and IE8

Comment: Well what happens?  Is there no response at all? What "Content-Type" is the server sending?  Does the server have gzip compression enabled?

Comment: What exactly happens? What does `OmanPath()` contain?

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `self` with:

```
document.location.href
```

Comment: @Pooja, what does OmanPath() evaluate to, did you make sure the path is correct.

Comment: It gives the path from the root

Comment: @Pointy, Content-Type is application/zip